# Wrong price cart exeeding stock 1.9.3.3

Tags: cart, price, addtocart, product-prices, magento-1.9.3.3

When entering increasing the amount of products in the cart, so the stock will be exceeded, the cart is displaying wrong prices.

This happens with simple products.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug introduce in Magento 1.9.3.0. Not sure what reason for the change but this person's post was the same solution that I came to: https://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades/Cart-displays-wrong-price-after-exceeding-stock-value-Version-1/m-p/72784/highlight/true#M2453